# Algebraic solution for a equation involving radicals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x)=-\frac{5-x}{\sqrt{(5-x)^2+4}}-\frac{5-x}{\sqrt{(5-x)^2+9}}+1$$

I'm having trouble solving $f(x)=0$.

I know there is a root for this function, I took the steps to set $f(x)$ to be equal to zero, moved one to the other side, made a common denominator, multiplied the denominator out to the other side and expanded the square root multiplication.

So I got as far as this:

$$(5-x)\left(\sqrt{(5-x)^2+4}+\sqrt{(5-x)^2+9}\right)=\sqrt{x^4-20x^3+163x^2-630x+986}$$

I feel like the extra addition operation isn't making this very easy.

Is there even an algebraic solution to this? (e.g. expressed like $\sqrt 3$ or something)

If there is, how on earth do you get it?

Comment: There is an expression in radicals, but it's not very nice: After some rearranging, the (I think sole) root is $5 - \sqrt{25 + \alpha}$, where $\alpha$ a particular root of an irreducible quartic with integer but large and unpleasant coefficients. If you want to find an explicit expression, you can in principle use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation , but I'd avoid this if possible.

Comment: There it is, [not sure you want to see it :)](http://goo.gl/gLZYWh)

Comment: @Travis Not very nice indeed. I think I'll avoid the explicit expression...

Answer (score 2):

Facing so awful expressions, just be lazy and start defining $u=5-x$. So the equation to solve becomes $$\frac u{\sqrt{u^2+4}}+\frac u{\sqrt{u^2+9}}=1$$ Remove the denominators and obtain $$u{\sqrt{u^2+4}}+u{\sqrt{u^2+9}}={\sqrt{u^2+4}}{\sqrt{u^2+9}}$$ Now square a first time and simplify $$2u^2\sqrt{(u^2+4)(u^2+9)}=36-u^4$$ Square again to finally obtain $$3 u^8+52 u^6+216 u^4-1296=0$$ which is a quartic polynomial in $u^2$ which can be solved with radicals. However, the result will look like a serious nightmare.

Using Newton method and starting at $x_0=\frac 72$, the first interate is $$x_1=\frac {1650 \sqrt{5}-3143}{152}\approx 3.595475$$ which is quite close to the solution ($\approx3.593004$).

But, using instead Halley method and starting at $x_0=\frac 72$, the first interate is $$x_1=\frac{590601300 \sqrt{5}-1319047459}{438976} \approx 3.592897$$

But, using instead Householder method and starting at $x_0=\frac 72$, the first interate is $$x_1=\frac{194160244080750 \sqrt{5}-434153226752371}{633881344} \approx 3.593007$$

Another thing you could do is to expand the original function as a Taylor series built at $x=\frac 72$ and get $$f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}-\frac{2}{5}\right)-\left(\frac{32}{125}+\frac{8}{15
   \sqrt{5}}\right) \left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)\left(\frac{288}{3125}+\frac{8}{75
   \sqrt{5}}\right) \left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^3\right)$$ Keeping the development ot second order and solving the quadratic gives $$x\approx \frac{912+100 \sqrt{5}+25 \sqrt{530+828 \sqrt{5}}}{432+100 \sqrt{5}}\approx 3.593027$$ which is better than Newton or Halley first iterates.